# How to run docker-compose across different lifecycle environments

Tags: docker-compose

How to run docker-compose across different lifecycle environments (say dev, qa, staging, production).
Sometimes a larger VM is being shared by multiple developers, so would like to start the containers with appropriate developer specific suffixes (say dev1, dev2, dev3 ..). Should port customization be handled manually via the environment file (i.e. .env file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unusual use case for docker-compose, but I'll leave some tips anyway! :)

There's two different ways to name stuff you start with docker-compose. One is to name the *service* that you specify under the main `services:` key of your docker-compose.yml file. By default, individual running *containers* will be assigned names indicating what project they are from (by default, the name of the directory from which your docker-compose file is in), what service they run (this is what's specified under your `services:` key), and which instance of that service they are (this number changes if eg. you're using `replica`s). Eg. default container names for a service named `myservice` specified in a compose file `~/my_project/docker/docker-compose.yml` will have a name like `docker_myservice_1` (or `_2`, `_3`, etc if more than one container is supposed to run).

You can use environment variables to specify a lot of key-value pairs in docker-compose files, but you *can't* conditionally specify the service name - service keys are only allowed to have alphanumeric characters in them and compose files *can't* look like eg:

```
version: "3"

services:
  ${ENVVAR}:
    image: ubuntu:20.04
```

However, you can override the *container* naming scheme by using the `container_name` field in your docker-compose file (documentation for usage [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#container_name)). *Maybe* a solution you could use looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  myservice:
    image: ubuntu:20.04
    container_name: ${DEVELOPER_ENVVAR?err}
```

this will require a developer to specify DEVELOPER_ENVVAR at runtime, either by exporting it in their shell or by running docker-compose like `DEVELOPER_ENVVAR=myservice_dev1 docker-compose up`. Note that using container_name is incompatible with using replicas to run multiple containers for the same service - the names have to be unique for those running containers, so you'll either have to define separate services for each name, or give up on using `container_name`.

However, you're in a pickle if you expect multiple developers to be able to run containers with different names using the *same* compose file in the same directory. That's because when starting a service, docker-compose has a `Recreating` step where, if there's already containers implementing that service running, they'll wait for that container to finish. Ultimately, I think this is for the best - if multiple developers were trying to run the exact same compose project at once, should a developer have control over other developers' running containers? Probably not, right?

If you want multiple developers to be able to run services at once in the same VM, I think you probably want to do two things:

- first, (and you may well have already done this! but it's still a good reminder) make sure that this is a good idea. Are there going to be resource contention issues (eg. for port-forwarding) that make different running instances of your project conflict? For *many* Docker services, there are going to be, but there probably won't be for eg. images that are meant to be run in a swarm.
- second, have different compose files checked out in different directories, so that there are separate compose projects for each developer. To use `.env` files one way one obvious option is to just maintain separate copies, one per developer directory. If, for your use case, it's unsatisfactory to maintain one copy of `.env` per developer this way, you could use symlinks named `.env` (or whatever your env file is named) to the same file somewhere else on the VM.

After you've done this, you'll be able to tell from the container names who is running what.

If none of these are satisfactory, you might want to consider, eg. using one VM per developer, or maybe even considering using a different container management system than docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

I have done very similar automation and I've used Ansible to create "docker compose" config on the fly.
So based  on input-Environment , the ansible playbook will create the  relevant docker-compose file. So basically I have a docker-compose  `template` in my git repository with values that are dynamic and ansible playbook populates them  etc.

and also you can use ansible to trigger such creation or automation one after another

A similar sample has been posted at [ansible_docker_splunk](https://github.com/getkub/ansible_docker_splunk/tree/master/ansible/roles/build_splunk_compose) repository.
Basically the whole project is to automate end-to-end docker cluster from CSV file